# how to use python programs on TI Nspire CX CAS calculator

Tags: python, calculator, micropython, ti-nspire

I am very new to this. can someone please explain how can I open a tns file containing a python program made using TI Nspire CX CAS Student software v5.4.0.259 into my nspire CX CAS calculator, when i open the file it says it was made with newer version of software and cant be opened.
on the other hand I have successfully installed ndless and micropythin on my calculator that has v4.5.4.48. but the micropythin is just a blank page and i have no idea how I open the python programs.

please help

Comment: Have you updated your CX CAS to the latest version?
https://education.ti.com/da/software/update/ti-nspire-software-update

Comment: Updating the firmware wouldn't help because python is not officially available on CX (but only on CX II). In fact the ndless jailbreak is not available for latest firmware.

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice it was an old model.